# How to dynamically adjust the radius of a Heatmap in Openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to show signal strength of a transmitter. My goal is to keep the colors and the radius as I zoom in or out. Setting a function instead of an Int value does not work. How can this be achieved in OL3?

```
var map = new ol.Map({...});
var source = new ol.source.ServerVector({...});

var heatMap = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    title: 'Heatmap',
    source: source,
    radius: function() {
        return 300 / map.getView().getResolution();
    }
});

map.addLayer(heatMap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use setRadius to change the radius on the fly? Use a change:resolution listener on the view to get notified when the resolution changes and call setRadius.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I tried this, but looked for resolution changes on the map object and not on the view. Thanks!